# Traffic emulator by using particle simulation

Tags: particles

I see that blender has pretty impressive physics for controlling particle behaviour for a simulation. My main aim is creating a simulation of multiple cars in a traffic situation (like just a highway, or a road with some cuts). In this situation I'd like to have control of every particle (car). Like for example, the reactions on the basis of outside conditions. So, if there's a car in front of the current car, then it shouldn't move ahead.

If there is some space on the left, and it is more than the size of the particle then it should move to the left, et cetera. So how should I program such behavior into the simulation?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is totally out of range of blender's particule system. Consider using c and x11 or python and tk. But this would work on 2d only.

Comment: Given that traffic simulation/optimization is an entire branch of research, this is as of now very out of scope for Blender. In theory someone could implement this, but surely nothing you just add easily.

Comment: @rjg Thanks for your comment. Could you suggest something for this use case?

Comment: There is an add-on in development by Jeroen Bakker for traffic simulation which presented at the Blender Conference at this very moment.